# How to set and import new from / to date products with magmi?

Tags: magmi

I made 2 columns news_from_date and news_to_date, tried all possibilities DD.MM.YY,MM-DD-YY,YY/DD/MM .... and after import with MAGMI, the item's are not set to that date.Do you have any other better ideea, or am I doind something wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Trying using the date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

As suggested by: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5100/593